# Strange merge "Already up to date"

Tags: git, visual-studio

I have two local branches A and B in Visual Studio. They also exist as remote branches (remotes/origin)
I have checked out branch A and do 'git merge B'.
Git Bash command prompt or in Visual Studio has the same result:
`warning refname 'B' is ambiguous. Already up to date`

Is there a way to tell git that B refers to the local branch B and not to the remote branch B, the warning is not necessary?

When I do the command in Visual Studio, it warns me before executing the merge command: 258 files with potential conflicts, which most certainly is not true.

There certainly are changes in B and A, B everything is pulled (up-to-date also with prune).
Any idea how this would be possible?

Comment: I don't think this should happen if you have a **local** branch called `B`. Is that the case? If it is the case, can you _show_ us in the question with the output of `git branch -a | grep B`?

Comment: Output is `B remotes/origin/B` with a newline in between

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be explicit:

```
For a local branch: `refs/heads/B`
For a remote branch: `refs/remotes/origin/B`
```

To merge the local branch B into A, while on branch A, you can use:

```
git merge refs/heads/B
```

Comment: makes sense but I get the answer `merge: refs/heads/B - not something we can merge`

Comment: First, make sure that the local branch B does exist and you have checked out branch A `git branch` -OR- Try Fetching and Merging the Remote Version `git fetch origin` and `git merge origin/B`. -OR- do a comparison `git log A..B`

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if `git fetch origin` solves this.

After this `git merge origin/B` works.
Maybe `git merge B` also works (I couldn't check that).

Also after `git fetch origin`
`git merge refs/heads/B` doesn't give the output `merge: refs/heads/B - not something we can merge` any more but a correct answer.